# Why after LEFT JOIN some rows duplicate itself?

Tags: mysql

**transaction_jobs table**

[image]

**transaction_lines table**

[image]

**SQL executed :**

```
SELECT 
tj.id AS tj_id, tj.debit AS tj_debit, tj.credit AS tj_credit, job_id AS tj_job_id,
tl.id AS tl_id, tl.debit AS tl_debit, tl.credit AS tl_credit
FROM transaction_jobs  tj
LEFT JOIN transaction_lines tl ON tl.account_id = tj.account_id AND tl.transaction_id = tj.transaction_id
WHERE tj.transaction_id = 198044 AND tj.account_id = 64375
```

**Executed code result:**

[image]

**Result I expected:**

[image]

Is there a way I could get the result I expected?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple records of the same transaction on both tables and are matching multiple times.

TJ ID 385610 will match once with TL ID 2277 and again with TL ID 2278. because both have transaction_id 198044.

If you wish for the results to be only one match, you need to use

> GROUP BY tj_transaction_id

You can read more here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: pretty sure if I use tj.transaction_id it will return one result isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

To use it in a GROUP BY or elsewhere in your query?